# CakePHP 1.3 associations

Tags: php, associations, cakephp-1.3

I've started writing a project using [CakePHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CakePHP) (1.3) and am finding it difficult to return results using the CakePHP style of querying.

The project is an issue tracker. So far I only have the following tables - 'users', 'projects' and a link table 'projects_users' because any users can be associated with one or more projects. There is also a 'statuses' table linked to the projects table.

I have set up the associations in the models.

I am trying to return a summary page for those logged in displaying  the project name, the status of the project filtered by the logged in `user_id`. If I did this in SQL then I would do something like the following.

```
SELECT
  `statuses`.name,
  `projects`.name
FROM
  `statuses`
  INNER JOIN `projects` ON (`statuses`.id = `projects`.status_id)
  INNER JOIN `projects_users` ON (`projects`.id = `projects_users`.project_id)
  INNER JOIN `users` ON (`projects_users`.user_id = `users`.id)
WHERE
  `users`.id = 1
```

`$this->Project->find('all'))` returns **all** projects, status details and user details.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Project] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [name] => Project 1
                        [status_id] => 2
                        [date_created] => 0000-00-00
                    )

                [Status] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [name] => Live
                    )
                [User] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 1
                                [username] => d
                                [password] => ********************************
                                [role] => master
                                [ProjectsUser] => Array
                                    (
                                        [id] => 1
                                        [project_id] => 1
                                        [user_id] => 1
                                    )
                            )
                    )
            )

Etc..
```

I have also tried

```
$this->Project->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'))))
```

which returns an error:

> Unknown column 'User.id' in 'where clause'

If I try

```
$this->Project->User->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'))))
```

it correctly returns all projects associated with the user_id, but now I am no longer returning the value of status, just the id.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [User] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [username] => d
                    [password] => ********************************
                    [role] => master
                )

            [Project] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [name] => Project 1
                            [status_id] => 2
                            [date_created] => 0000-00-00
                            [ProjectsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [project_id] => 1
                                    [user_id] => 1
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 3
                            [name] => Project 3
                            [status_id] => 1
                            [date_created] => 0000-00-00
                            [ProjectsUser] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [project_id] => 3
                                    [user_id] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Is there a way to easily return what I'm after the 'CakePHP' way? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious here.

Answer (score 0):

> which returns an error - Unknown column 'User.id' in 'where clause'

Your table name is `users`. Plural. You passed it something not `users`.

Comment: Good thought, but

$this->Project->find('all', array('conditions'=>array('Users.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id'))))

still gives the error.

I believe that cake requires 'user' rather than users because I am filtering on a single user. The other query that has 'user' works also?

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
$this->Project->User->find(
    'all',
    array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'User.id' => $this->Session->read('Auth.User.id')
        ),
        'contain' => array(
            'Project' => array(
                'Status'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

I might have your relations wrong but that should do the trick. It's `containable` that you want. `containable` is a core library, but will not join. If you really want joins there is a linkable behavior that Google can find for you.

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. Unfortunately it returns exactly the same as my second example i.e the status_id and not the status. For clarity the Projects table has the FK of status_id

Comment: well then you must have 'fields' => array('Status.id') defined in your relation. you can extend the above to 'Status' => array('fields' => array('Status.id', 'Status.name'))

@peter, could you stop editing my posts ktx

Comment: I don't have 'fields' => array('Status.id') defined, but I thought that this just meant that all fields would be returned by default. Expanding 'Status' has made no difference. I have checked and re-checked my models, and everything else works as I would expect, but not this.

Comment: if u do not have fields defined or 'fields' => array() // empty it will pull all the fields on that relation.

do you have debug on and is there any errors showing (grasping at straws) i cant think of anything atm.

maybe it should be ::

'contain' => array(
            'Project',
            'Status'
        )

Comment: Try adding 'recursive' => 2 so it drills down further. You can read more about it here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/1063/recursive

Comment: @cdburgess that is horrible advice. if you are using recursive 2 in your code, it wont be long before your server dies.